# c++ Initialize Adobe Reader automation

Tags: c++, winapi, pdf, adobe, ole

I have code showed below to open adobe reader. I inspirated from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8763/A-simple-wrapper-to-control-Acrobat-Reader-from-yo
Everytime adobe reader is not opened and DdeConnect returns null, so I get DDE connection failed. My adobe reader is: Adobe reader XI, version 11.0. Do you know to help me to connect to adobe reader?

I have to use pure c++ and win32 api.

```
iReturn = DdeInitialize(&this->dwIdInst, (PFNCALLBACK)DdeCallback,
        APPCLASS_STANDARD | APPCMD_CLIENTONLY, 0 );
/*Start the DDE server*/
hRet = ShellExecute(0, "open", this->stPdfFileName.c_str(), 0, 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

/*Connect to server*/
HSZ hszApp, hszTopic;
char szApp[] = "acroviewR11"; // Also I tried acroviewA11
char szTopic[] = "control";

hszApp = DdeCreateStringHandle(this->dwIdInst, szApp, 0);
hszTopic = DdeCreateStringHandle(this->dwIdInst, szTopic, 0);

this->hConv = DdeConnect(this->dwIdInst, hszApp, hszTopic, NULL);

DdeFreeStringHandle(this->dwIdInst, hszApp);
DdeFreeStringHandle(this->dwIdInst, hszTopic);

if (this->hConv == NULL) {
    printf("DDE Connection Failed.\n");
    Sleep(1500);
    DdeUninitialize(this->dwIdInst);
}
```

**UPDATE**

I don't want to only open document. I want to automate some things thanks to adobe reader automation like showed in added link upper.

I also tried code like this:

```
DdeInitialize(&id, &DDE_ProcessMessage, APPCMD_CLIENTONLY, 0);
hszServerName = DdeCreateStringHandle(id, "Acrobat Search", 0);
hszTopicName = DdeCreateStringHandle(id, "Acrobat Search", 0);
hConv = DdeConnect(id, hszServerName, hszTopicName, NULL);
```

But it doesn't help me.

Comment: Just use `ShellExecuteEx` with `NULL` for the verb. If Acrobat Reader is the default PDF viewer it will open.

Comment: This not helps me, because I want to automate adobe reader next. For example automate close document, save document and some other things which are mentioned in added simple wrapper link

Answer (score 0):

use "AcroViewR11" instead of "acroviewR11".